# Максимальный элемент кратный 4

Tags: java

Всем привет. В IDEA проходит, но при проверке решения - ошибка. Задача. Дана последовательность натуральных чисел, не превышающая 30000. Найти максимальный элемент, кратный 4. Программа получает количество элементов в последовательности, а затем сами элементы в качестве входных данных. В последовательности всегда присутствует элемент, делимый на 4. Количество элементов не превышает 1000. Программа должна вывести одно число: максимальный элемент последовательности, делимый на 4.
Пример ввода:

```
4 
16 
2 
5
10
```

Пример вывода:

```
16
```

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MaximumElementDivisibleBy4 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = scanner.nextInt();
    if (number > 30000) {
      System.out.println("number>30000");
    } else {
      BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      int[] m = new int[number];
      for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        m[i] = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
      }
      int max = m[0];
      if (max > 1000) {
        System.out.println("max>1000");
      } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
          if (max < m[i] && m[i] % 4 == 0) {
            max = m[i];
          }
        }
        System.out.println(max);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы совершенно зря пишете в программе валидацию входных данных. По условию даны данные и они будут правильные. Вам нужно убрать вот эти части:

```
if (number > 30000) {

 if (max > 1000) {
```

И массив не нужен.

Основная ошибка в том, что вы неверно построили алгоритм поиска наибольшего по условию. Для поиска максимума нужно корректное начальное значение. В вашем примере вам повезло и оно было первым в последовательности (16). В общем случае надо найти первое нужное число и установить его как начальное значение переменной mMax.

Вот пример кода

```
int doWeSeeSpecialNumberBefore=0;
      int m,mMax;
      for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        m = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
        if (m %4==0){
            if (doWeSeeSpecialNumberBefore==0){mMax=m;doWeSeeSpecialNumberBefore=1;}
            else
             if (m>mMax){mMax=m;}
        }
      }
```

Переменная doWeSeeSpecialNumberBefore это признак того первое ли мы видим число, которое делится на 4 или не первое.

Comment: Зачем нужен `state`, если `mMax` можно смело инициализировать значением  -2147483648? Постулат "входные данные верны" включает в себя в т.ч. и "входные данные не пусты".

Comment: Затем что это понятно и наглядно и всегда работает в любом языке программирования. Инициализация -MAXINT это костыль.

Comment: @Akina я хотел предложить использовать что-нибудь вроде NEGATIVE_INFINITY, а оно только дробных чисел есть :/

Comment: @Akina Решение задачи валидации данных для проверки задачи в системе автоматизированного тестирования типичная ошибка. Это решение другой задачи.

Comment: *Инициализация -MAXINT это костыль*  Ну это, наверное, всё же дело вкуса, а не костыль. А комментарий с пояснением, почему такое значение, ещё нагляднее и понятнее.

Comment: Не очень понятно суть проблемы. Лишняя переменная? Я ее ввел, чтобы человеку было понятно.

Comment: @Akina Собственно это в чистом виде костыль. Мое решение легко исправить для поиска максимума и минимума для любого условия. В случае вашего -MAXINT нужно каждый раз придумывать новое начальное значение.

Comment: @becouse да, лишняя переменная, которая затрудняет чтение, да ещё и неподходящего типа. Для бинарных значений есть boolean.

Comment: @Эникейщик Переименовал специально для комфортного чтения. Вообще это примитивный стандартный алгоритм описанный у Вирта, в нем нет ничего сложного.

Comment: Ну относительно костыльности спорить не буду. Хотя отмечу, что MIN_INT подходит для поиска минимума при любом условии.

Comment: @Akina А если вещественные числа в массиве? Каждый раз новое начальное значение. Это постоянное придумывание костылей для стандартной задачи.

Comment: @Akina, не минимума, а максимума.